# I need to copy a spreadsheet into mail directly edit and send

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to copy a spreadsheet into mail directly and then edit out some columns before sending (not as an attachment) what ipad spreadsheet an mail will work?

Comment: more details please

Answer (score 1):

Numbers can do that.   Except the "not attachment bit', but if you select the bit that you want you can paste it directly into your E-mail.